# OutOfMemoryException, I suspect the cause is the DbContext, but I'm not sure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-leaks, entity-framework-6, out-of-memory

We are having an issue, at some random point in time the application would just throw an outOfMemoryException that I'm unable to consistently reproduce on my local. I have used the Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio, ANTS Memory Profiler, also created a DUMP file and analized it and everything seems to be pointing at a list of strings created somewhere and not being cleaned by the GC.

When I look at the instances of string in the Diagnostic tools in visual studio it seems that the context is creating more strings and somehow this is linked to the DbContext, I'm not 100% sure why yet. Also when I checked the instances with the ANTS Memory profilers all the strings seemed like Column db names, Db MetaData..etc.

[image]

Any comment/help/recommendation would be appreciated.

**Exception(EDIT):**

```
                    Exception type: OutOfMemoryException 
                Exception message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadPlpUnicodeChars(Char[]& buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32& totalCharsRead)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String columnName)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
            at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
            at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
            at Repositories.AttributeAreaRepository.ActiveAttributesStringForOptions(Int32 builderId, Int32 divisionId, Nullable`1 phasePlanId) in D:\SSSource\Projects\Repositories\AttributeAreaRepository.cs:line 176
            at Web.Areas.Customer.Models.CustomerController.Options(Nullable`1 isSpectOptionTab) in D:\SSSource\Websites\Web\Areas\Customer\Controllers\CustomerController.cs:line 4311
            at Web.Areas.Spec.Controllers.SpecOptionController.Index() in D:\SSSource\Websites\Web\Areas\Spec\Controllers\SpecOptionController.cs:line 35
            at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
            at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
            at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
            at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

> Blockquote

Comment: @Symon, no, CodeReview is for reviewing working and complete code.

Comment: @GertArnold , wouldn't this count as Working and Complete just bad optimization?

Comment: @Symon I don't see any code. There's nothing to be reviewed here.

Comment: @Symon no, this is not working and complete.  There is a bug that is causing a malfunction.  This issue is "help me find my bug", not "help me improve my style".

Comment: This is a very common occurrence when you forget to dispose of things.  It is probably not connections, since they are quite a limited resource so you would soon run out of them, but it can be any of the objects that you use within the context of a connection.  It is usually result set.  That you create, enumerate, and forget to dispose of.

Comment: The strings are a red herring in this case, they show in the memory profiler because they are most numerous and they occupy the most space, but the culprit is some other structure that owns those strings.  All I can suggest to you is to review all the library classes and interfaces that you are using, figure out which ones are `IDisposable`, and make sure they are all disposed.

Comment: Please post some of your code that may be relevant, specifically your `DbContext`.

Comment: What you see is probably Entity Framework's model metadata. This metadata is stored once in the app domain for each `DbContext` class, so EF doesn't have to build it each time a context is constructed. In other words, this is intended behavior. You should look for resources that occupy growing amounts of memory while the application runs. We don't have much to go by without code. You don't even tell what kind of application this is.

Comment: The Problem with OutOfMemoryException is , that the code that throws the exception is not often the real problem. Run The Application for a while and use a memory profiler

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, @ManuelAmstutz as you can read I already did that.

Comment: I haven't posted any code because I have no idea where the issue is

Comment: I EDITED and you can see the exception, but it doesn't happens there always, sometimes there sometimes at a different place

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the Problem with the same database on your machine?
I bet it is a ".ToList()" with a huge data set